# Implementation of Iterable in Java

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, adt

```
//project.java
import MULTISET;
public class Bag<E extends Keyed> implements Iterable<E> {
    //cannot find symbol. symbol: class Iterator. location: class project.Bag<E> 
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new ArrIterator(this);
    }
    //same error as above        
    public class ArrIterator implements Iterator<E> {    
        Bag<E> arr;
        int coun;    
        public ArrIterator(Bag<E> arr) {
            this.arr = arr;
            this.coun = 0;
        }    
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.coun < arr.cardinality();
        }    
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoItemException();
            }
            return arr.getArray()[coun+1];
        }    
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }    
}

//MULTISET.java
//cannot find symbol. symbol: class Iterator. location: interface MultiSet<E>
public interface MultiSet<E extends Keyed> extends Iterable<E> {
    public Iterator<E> iterator();
}
```

I'm trying to do foreach loops on type Bag, and I get the two commented errors. I'm not too familiar with ADT, generics, or iterators, but I thought I did the correct thing.

What is missing and/or wrong here? This isn't my complete code, but everything else I've left out works. There's a problem somewhere in the above code snippet. An example I was following is more or less 1:1 with my own code, but mine doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Change return type for hasNext() to boolean instead of Boolean.

Comment: Just a thought: if you're passing a `Bag` in the constructor for `ArrIterator` then you should declare `ArrIterator` as a `static` class (or even move it to a separate compilation unit).

Comment: 'coun+1' should be 'coun++' in next(), although why you want to abbreviate 'count' is a mystery.

Comment: @EJP, `int count` is another variable declared beforehand as public.

Comment: That's not a valid reason. The `ArrIterator `class opens a complete new scope. Actually it isn't a count at all, it is an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your inner class `ArrIterator` is re-defining another generic type parameter `<E>` when it's still in scope from your outer class, `Bag`.  This causes the new `E` not to match the old `E`.

According to [Section 6.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a class's type parameter (§8.1.2) is the type parameter section of the class declaration, the type parameter section of any superclass or superinterface of the class declaration, and the class body.

Remove the re-declaration of `E` in your inner class `ArrIterator` and let its `extends` clause use the `E` already in scope.

```
public class ArrIterator implements Iterator<E> {
```

Then your `iterator()` method doesn't have to return a generic `ArrIterator`.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new ArrIterator(this);
}
```

Also, your `hasNext` method in your iterator should return `boolean` to match the `Iterator` interface.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation, helps me get my head in the right direction. Regarding your second code snippet, I get the same error: `iterator() in Bag cannot implement iterator() in Iterable. return type Package.Iterator<E> is not compatible with java.util.Iterator<E> where E,T are type-variables`. Adding `@Override` doesn't change nothing, either.

Comment: @riista You have to do both changes.

Comment: @riista With the changes in my answer, I can eliminate the relevant error messages you're receiving.  If you have additional error messages, then it appears to be from code you haven't shown here, perhaps it's with `Package.Iterator<E>`.

Comment: @rgettman, I've fiddled a little bit with the code and got those errors to go away. However, a couple others have popped up. The unshown code doesn't conflict with anything here, as the errors are referencing only classes within what I included. I've edited the question with new code.